# How to Loop through a Table of values in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table that is being populated from database through an angularJS array.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Budget Amount</th>
            <th>Actual Amount</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="lineItem in vm.budget.budgetLines">
            <td>
                {{lineItem.code}}
            </td>

            <td>@{{lineItem.description}}</td>
            <td>{{lineItem.budgetAmount | currency}}</td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="lineItem.actualAmount" required /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The data population works fine. But if you look at the table, you would notice an input field in the last column. I need to be able to perform an update with changes made to the input for which I need just the 1st and last column for the operation. I used the following approach but it didn't work because it just used the original values with which the table was first populated.

```
$scope.lineItems = [];

for (var i = 0; i < vm.budget.budgetLines.length; i++) {
    var lineItem = vm.budget.budgetLines[i];
    $scope.lineItems.push({
        'code': lineItem.code,
        'actualAmount': lineItem.actualAmount
    });
}
```

So I thought of using pure javascript inside my angular controller to loop through the table rows and push the columns I need in the array like so;

```
var myTable = document.getElementById("tblValues");
var current, cell;
for (var i = 0; i < myTable.rows.length ; i++) {
    var rowItem = myTable.rows[i];
    $scope.lineItems.push({
        'code': rowItem.cells[1],
        'actualAmount': rowItem.cells[4].children[0].value
    });
}
```

But an error is thrown in the console: **rowItem.cells[4].children[0] is undefined**

Please how can I get this to work just the way I want it?

Comment: Extract the related code into a working demo (using Plunker, for example) and people here can help you have a look. From your code above, I can only say `rowItem.cells[4].children[0]` is undefined, you can easily log the content of `rowItem` to check.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work just the way I desired it to.

```
var myTable = document.getElementById("tblValues");
var current, cell;
$scope.lineItems.length = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < myTable.rows.length ; i++) {
    var rowItem = myTable.rows[i + 1];
    $scope.lineItems.push({
        'code': rowItem.cells[1].innerText,
        'actualAmount': rowItem.cells[4].firstChild.value
    });
}
```